# How to enable SRTP with pjsip in android?

Tags: android, ssl, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm setting TLS + SRTP on my VoIP app in android. So far i have compiled PJSIP 2.8 with OpenSSL 1.0.2g. making call without srtp works fine, but when i force to use SRTP, call in not make.

I enable SRTP with following code:

```
AccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY);
AccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(1);
```

TLS works fine, because if I set secureSignaling to 1 (need TLS transport) and srtpUse to disable, I still can make call and it works fine.

I checked my server with Zoiper, and Zoiper could make a secure call.
So, I'm sure problem is from my configuration of SRTP.

This is my configs on Android App:

TLS Transport :

```
sipTpConfig.getTlsConfig().setMethod(pjsip_ssl_method.PJSIP_TLSV1_METHOD);
sipTpConfig.getTlsConfig().setVerifyServer(false);
sipTpConfig.getTlsConfig().setVerifyClient(false);
sipTpConfig.getTlsConfig().setRequireClientCert(false);
Port = 5061
```

and Media Config:

```
AccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpUse(pjmedia_srtp_use.PJMEDIA_SRTP_MANDATORY);
AccountConfig.getMediaConfig().setSrtpSecureSignaling(1);
AccountConfig.getMediaConfig().getTransportConfig().getTlsConfig().setMethod(pjsip_ssl_method.PJSIP_TLSV1_METHOD);
```

In my Server (Asterisk 13.26) I have these configs:

Sip.conf :

```
[general]
context=internal
externaddr= 192.168.1.2
externip= 192.168.1.2
externtcpport=5060
externudpport=5060
externtlsport=5061
tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0:5060
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0:5060
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:5061
allowguest=no
allowoverlap=no
srvlookup=no
allow=all
alwaysauthreject=yes
canreinvite=no
nat=force_rport,comedia
session-timers=refuse
localnet=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
tcpenable=yes
srtpcapable=yes
tlsenable=yes
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
tlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
tlscipher=ALL
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1
encryption=yes
direct_media=no
media_encryption_optimistic=false
media_encryption=sdes

[6002]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=12345
context=internal
transport=tls
```

had anyone same issue or know a way to fix this ?

Log files of android and asterisk :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18j98zp9FWJGRSvRdKy5k96VNbjUYaRc5/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eAeX5Gd6phIvKDLCRjVyD6uZV_CP9h6p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ali Ghasemi have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: Ali Ghasemi have you found any solution for this problem ?

Comment: May you try to enable TLS in the endpoint config?